# Extract then stack the high and low bytes from an array of image bytes

Tags: java, image, byte, preprocessor, data-extraction

I'm relatively new to doing image compression on the byte level, and am currently working on a java image preprocessor that will take a bmp image, convert it to an 8-bit unsigned grayscale, then stack its bytes according to high and low before exporting and compressing it. After some extensive research and testing various methods of byte extraction, I'm still not seeing the results I need. Before I continue, it should be noted that all of these images are originally in DICOM format, and I'm using the ij.plugin.DICOM package to extract the pixel data as a bmp image.

The following description is represented by code bellow. Currently, I'm reading in the original image as a buffered image, converting it to grayscale, then getting the image bytes from the Raster. Then I take those bytes, and using some other code I found on stackoverflow and "converting" them to a String representation of binary bits. I then send that string to a character array. The next step might be extraneous, but I wanted to get your input before I removed it (since I'm new at this). I make a Bitset and iterate through the "binary" character array. If the character value is "1", I set that position in the BitSet to true. Then I send the BitSet to another byte array.

Then I make two new byte arrays, one for the high and one for the low byte. Using a for loop, I'm iterating over the "bit" array and storing every 4 "bits" in the high or low byte, depending on where we are in the array.

Lastly, I take the DICOM tag data, make a byte array from it, and then stack the tag array, the high byte array, and the low byte array together. My intended result is to have the image matrix be "split" with the top half containing all the high bytes and the bottom half containing all of the low bytes. I've been told that the tag bytes will be so small, they shouldn't affect the final outcome (I've tested the image without them, just to be sure, and there was no visible difference).

Below is the code. Please let me know if you have any questions, and I will modify my post accordingly. I've tried to include all relevant data. Let me know if you need more.

```
        BufferedImage originalImage = getGrayScale(img.getBufferedImage());//returns an 8-bit unsigned grayscale conversion of the original image
        byte[] imageInByte = ((DataBufferByte) originalImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        String binary = toBinary(imageInByte); //converts to a String representation of the binary bits
        char[] binCharArray = binary.toCharArray();
        BitSet bits = new BitSet(binCharArray.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < binCharArray.length; i++) {
            if (binCharArray[i] == '1') {
                bits.set(i);
            }
        }
        imageInByte = bits.toByteArray();

        byte[] high = new byte[(int) imageInByte.length/2];
        byte[] low = new byte[(int) imageInByte.length/2];

        int highC = 0;
        int lowC = 0;
        boolean change = false; //start out storing in the high bit
        //change will = true on very first run. While true, load in the high byte array. Else low byte
        for(int i = 0; i < imageInByte.length; i++){
            if(i % 4 == 0){
                change = !change;
            }
            if(change){
                high[highC] = imageInByte[i];
                highC++;
            } else {
                low[lowC] = imageInByte[i];
                lowC++;
            }
        }
        //old code from a previous attempt. 
     // for (int j = 0; j < imageInByte.length; j++) {
     //       byte h = (byte) (imageInByte[j] & 0xFF);
     //       byte l = (byte) ((imageInByte[j] >> 8) & 0xFF);
     //       high[j] = h;
     //       low[j] = l;
     // }

        OutputStream out = null;
        //add this array to the image array. It goes at the beginning.
        byte[] tagBytes = dicomTags.getBytes();
        currProcessingImageTagLength = tagBytes.length;
        imageInByte = new byte[high.length + low.length + tagBytes.length];
        System.arraycopy(tagBytes, 0, imageInByte, 0, tagBytes.length);
        System.arraycopy(high, 0, imageInByte, tagBytes.length, high.length);
        System.arraycopy(low, 0, imageInByte, tagBytes.length + high.length, low.length);

        BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = new BufferedImage(dimWidth, dimHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);//dimWidth and dimHeight are the image dimensions, stored much earlier in this function
        byte[] bufferHolder = ((DataBufferByte) bImageFromConvert.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        System.arraycopy(imageInByte, 0, bufferHolder, 0, bufferHolder.length);
     //This is where I try and write the final image before sending it off to an image compressor
        ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "bmp", new File(
                directory + fileName + "_Compressed.bmp"));
        return new File(directory + fileName + "_Compressed.bmp");
```

And below is the toBinary function in case you were interested:

```
  private static String toBinary(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * Byte.SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < Byte.SIZE * bytes.length; i++) {
        sb.append((bytes[i / Byte.SIZE] << i % Byte.SIZE & 0x80) == 0 ? '0' : '1');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Thank you so much for your help! I've spent nearly 20 hours now trying to solve this one problem. It's been a huge headache, and any insight you have would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here's the getGreyScale function:

```
public static BufferedImage getGrayScale(BufferedImage inputImage) {
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(inputImage.getWidth(), inputImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(inputImage, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    return img;
}
```

EDIT 2: I've added some images upon request.

Current output:

[current image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm6A1.png)

Note, I can't post the images with the "expected" high byte and low byte outcome due to my reputation being lower than 10.

Comment: a) " to have the image matrix be "split" with the top half containing all the high bytes and the bottom half containing all of the low bytes.": so you want to have the high part of all bytes bunched together in the upper part of the image? what is the expected result? b) maybe it all has to do with dicom of which i dont know nothing but considered as simple steps of processing it should make sense what you expect and what you get

Comment: @gpasch a) Yes. The image should appear with all the high bytes bunched at the top and all the low bytes bunched at the bottom. In other words, the final image should be of the original dimensions, but the top half of the image is a mini bright image, and the bottom half is a mini dark image. b) For all intents and purposes, by the time the DICOM is being processed it should function as a normal bmp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This says every 4 bytes change; thats not what you intend:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < imageInByte.length; i++){
        if(i % 4 == 0){
            change = !change;
        }
        if(change){
            high[highC] = imageInByte[i];
            highC++;
        } else {
            low[lowC] = imageInByte[i];
            lowC++;
        }
    }
```

I would replace it with this, from your earlier attempt

```
  for (int j = 0; j < imageInByte.length; j+=2) {
        byte h = (byte) (imageInByte[j] & 0xF0);
        byte h2 = (byte) (imageInByte[j+1] & 0xF0);
        byte l = (byte) (imageInByte[j] & 0x0f);
        byte l2 = (byte) (imageInByte[j+1] & 0x0f);
        high[j/2] = h|(h2>>4);
        low[j/2] = (l<<4)|l2;
  }
```

Comment: Hmm, it definitely looks much closer to what I need, but it's still a bit off. Let me look through the code and make sure it's not something I'm doing.

Comment: there is the first part toGray which I dont know how it works and whether its correct; then there is the much fiddling with the bits in the middle - you have the binary I dont know why you need all that to String and back - and finally you can try to display the image as a JFrame before compression etc to make sure it is visually what you expect

Comment: Added the function to the question so you can look at it. I'm not sure if I need the String and back part or not. I'm just not fully clear how Java handles binary bits, or if it handles binary bits, and wanted to be sure. Do you think it inhibits my code?

Comment: I will check the code and see how it works a bit later - it doesnt inhibit just maybe hides some error potentially

Comment: I dont know why you say "a bit off" - it seems to work for me here (I excluded the dicom tags which I dont want and will not mess with) - otherwise post example images to illustrate what you expect - all the best

Comment: Ok, I added my current output with the modifications. As I said in the edit, I can't post my "expected" images because stack overflow won't allow additional links. If you need those images, I could try clumping everything together with a screenshot or in mspaint.